# Laravel app not connecting after deployment to live server

Tags: laravel

After deploying my Laravel app to inMotion hosting, I am having issues connecting to the database. What is strange is that if I use a PHP script to test the connection, it works. However, when trying to login I get this error:

> ```
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user @'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = .com limit
> ```
>
> 1. 

I am using the exact same username and password in the .env file as I did in the PHP test script. I have tried clearing the cache and also changing the password for the database as well as my username.

Comment: The content of your `.env` is probably incorrect

Comment: try writing your username - password and database name in "" ( as a string.) might help

Comment: It was indeed the .env. It was correct, but the pw had special characters and needed quotation marks.

Answer (score -1):

Better if you can clear the config cache and see. You can use the following command to clear the config cache in Laravel:

`php artisan config:cache`

Answer (score -1):

Turns out it was the password in the .env file. It had special characters, so I had to add quotation marks around it.